# Simulate HTTP Request with Guzzle or Curl

Tags: php, curl, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, guzzle

I'm trying to replicate the following HTTP request made by Amazon's UI tool to access their Marketplace Web Services (MWS API)

This is the request made when using their UI tool. Note, the HTTP request info was taken from Google Chrome's developer console.

**General**

Request URL:https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01

Request Method: POST

Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:54.239.24.6:443

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Request Headers**

POST /Products/2011-10-01 HTTP/1.1

Host: mws.amazonservices.com

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 309

Origin: https://mws.amazonservices.com

x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Accept: text/plain, */*

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Referer: https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Cookie: csm-hit=20.82|1494090798243

**Form Data**

AWSAccessKeyId: {{API KEY}}

Action:GetMatchingProductForId

SellerId: {{API KEY}}

SignatureVersion:2

Timestamp:2017-05-06T17:43:36Z

Version:2011-10-01

Signature:wVax9gw0DfIfeL7s4Z2IZynwwryi0c6tIkfE7IQY1RI=

SignatureMethod:HmacSHA256

MarketplaceId:ATVPDKIKX0DER

IdType:UPC

IdList.Id.1:034264456730

This is my PHP script using GuzzleHTTP library to try and emulate the request.

```
 <?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$body = 'AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFTQQL6UN7RO6WBQ&Action=GetMatchingProductForId&SellerId=AWWNSYIT4NM3&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2017-05-06T17%3A43%3A36Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=wVax9gw0DfIfeL7s4Z2IZynwwryi0c6tIkfE7IQY1RI%3D&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&IdType=UPC&IdList.Id.1=034264456730';

$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri'=>'https://mws.amazonservices.com',
    'cookies'=>$jar,
    'headers'=>[
        'User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36',
        'Host'=> 'mws.amazonservices.com',
        'Connection'=>'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length'=>'309',
        'Origin'=>'https://mws.amazonservices.com',
        'x-amazon-user-agent'=>'AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)',
        'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept'=>'text/plain, */*',
        'X-Requested-With'=>'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Referer'=>'https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html',
        'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language'=>'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        ],
    'body'=>$body,
    ]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01');

echo $response->getStatusCode();

?>
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Agam, I got a 400 bad request error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`form_params`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params) instead of `body`. And check the response, maybe Amazon says more than just `400 Bad Request` (response could contain more details about the error).